# Get permissions for all sites

Tags: 2010, powershell, sharepoint-server, permissions

Is there a generic powershell script that can output permissions (to csv) on all website within a site collection, as well as the top level site?

I tried a few that I found but none of them worked.

I am using SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Script. I use this for my sharepoint farm in my company.

```
############################
#
#   Author:         Manish Oswal
#   Created:        2011-01-07
#   Description:    Retrieves the users and their permissions from a Site
#
############################

# Clear the screen
CLS

# Stop on errors
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"


############################
##
## FUNCTIONS
##
############################

# Exports the permission groups and their permission levels to CSV
function exportPermissionGroup($fileNameToUse, $doExport)
{
    CLS

    # Check if the data need to be written to CVS
    if($doExport)
    {
        # Ask where to export the file + add the file name
        $exportPath = Select-Folder
        $exportPath +=  ("\" + $fileNameToUse + ".csv")

        # If the file exists, delete it
        deleteExisting -filePathToCheck $exportPath

        # Add the headers
        writeToCSV -textToWrite ("Group Name:;Roles:") -filePath $exportPath
    }

    # Loop through the groups
    foreach($group in $web.Groups)
    {               
        # Go through the roles
        $roleList = ""
        foreach($role in $group.Roles)
        {
            $roleList += (";" + $role.Name)
        }

        # Inform
        echo ("> " + $group.Name)
        echo ("  |-> " + $roleList.replace(";","`t"))
        echo ""

        # Check if the data need to be written to CVS
        if($doExport)
        {
            # Add the group name and the roles to the file
            writeToCSV -textToWrite ($group.Name + $roleList) -filePath $exportPath
        }
    }

    # Check if the data need to be written to CVS
    echo ""
    if($doExport)
    {
        Write-Warning ("The file has been stored at: " + $exportPath)
    }
    echo ""
}

# Exports the users and their permission levels to CSV
function exportWebUsers($fileNameToUse, $doExport)
{
    CLS

    # Create a variable to hold the users
    $userList = @()

    # Check if the data need to be written to CVS
    if($doExport)
    {
        # Ask where to export the file + add the file name
        $exportPath = Select-Folder
        $exportPath +=  ("\" + $fileNameToUse + ".csv")

        # If the file exists, delete it
        deleteExisting -filePathToCheck $exportPath

        # Add the headers
        writeToCSV -textToWrite ("User:;Display Name:;E-mail:;SharePoint ID:;Site Admin:;Permission Origin:") -filePath $exportPath
    }

    # Loop through the groups
    foreach($group in $web.Groups)
    {               
        # Loop through the users
        foreach($user in $group.Users)
        {
            # Get the user's information
            $userInfo = [String]::Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4};SP Group", $user.UserLogin, $user.DisplayName, $user.Email, $user.ID, $user.IsSiteAdmin)

            # Check if the user is not already in the list
            if(!($userList -contains $userInfo))
            {
                # Add the user to the list
                $userList += @($userInfo)
            }
        }
    }

    # Get the direct permissions on the site
    # Loop through the groups
    foreach($user in $web.Users)
    {
        # Get the user's information
        $userInfo = [String]::Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4};Direct", $user.UserLogin, $user.DisplayName, $user.Email, $user.ID, $user.IsSiteAdmin)

        # Check if the user is not already in the list
        if(!($userList -contains $userInfo))
        {
            # Add the user to the list
            $userList += @($userInfo)
        }
    }

    # Go through the list of users
    foreach($storedUser in $userList)
    {       
        # Inform
        echo ("> " + $storedUser.replace(";","`t"))

        # Check if the data need to be written to CVS
        if($doExport)
        {
            # Add the users to the file
            writeToCSV -textToWrite $storedUser -filePath $exportPath
        }
    }

    # Check if the data need to be written to CVS
    echo ""
    if($doExport)
    {
        Write-Warning ("The file has been stored at: " + $exportPath)
    }
    echo ""
}

# Exports the groups and the users of the web
function exportGroupAndUsers($fileNameToUse, $doExport)
{
    CLS

    # Check if the data need to be written to CVS
    if($doExport)
    {
        # Ask where to export the file + add the file name
        $exportPath = Select-Folder
        $exportPath +=  ("\" + $fileNameToUse + ".csv")

        # If the file exists, delete it
        deleteExisting -filePathToCheck $exportPath

        # Add the headers
        writeToCSV -textToWrite ("Group Name:;User:;Display Name:;E-mail:;SharePoint ID:;Site Admin:") -filePath $exportPath
    }

    # Loop through the groups
    foreach($group in $web.Groups)
    {
        # Check if there are users
        if($group.Users.Count -gt 0)
        {
            # Loop through the users
            foreach($user in $group.Users)
            {
                # Create the text
                $textToWrite = [String]::Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4};{5}", $group.Name,$user.UserLogin, $user.DisplayName, $user.Email, $user.ID, $user.IsSiteAdmin)

                # Inform
                echo ($textToWrite.replace(";","`t"))

                # Check if the data need to be written to CVS
                if($doExport)
                {
                    writeToCSV -textToWrite $textToWrite -filePath $exportPath
                }
            }
        }
        else # No users
        {
            # Create the text
            $textToWrite = [String]::Format("{0};[Empty]", $group.Name)

            # Inform
            echo ($textToWrite.replace(";","`t"))

            # Check if the data need to be written to CVS
            if($doExport)
            {
                writeToCSV -textToWrite $textToWrite -filePath $exportPath
            }
        }
    }


    # Check if the data need to be written to CVS
    echo ""
    if($doExport)
    {
        Write-Warning ("The file has been stored at: " + $exportPath)
    }
    echo ""
}

# Export single user information
function exportSingleUser($fileNameToUse, $doExport)
{
    CLS

    # Check if the data need to be written to CVS
    if($doExport)
    {
        # Ask where to export the file + add the file name
        $exportPath = Select-Folder
        $exportPath +=  ("\" + $fileNameToUse + ".csv")

        # If the file exists, delete it
        deleteExisting -filePathToCheck $exportPath
    }

    # Variable to hold the user information
    $userName = $null

    while($userName -eq $null)
    {
        # Ask for the user's login name
        $userName = Read-Host -Prompt "User to export information from - [domain\username]"

        # Variables to hold the group and user information
        $getUserGroups = $null
        $getUserInfo = $null

        try
        {
            # Try to retrieve the user information
            $getUserInfo = Get-SPUser -Web $web -Identity $userName

            # Check if there is data for this user in this web
            $getUserGroups = @($web.Groups | ?{$_.Users | ?{$_.UserLogin -eq $userName}})

            # Check if this user has information for this site
            if($getUserGroups.Count -eq 0)
            {
                # Trigger the catch block
                throw
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            # Show message
            #CLS
            echo ""
            Write-Warning "The user could not be found or is not member of any groups in this web"
            echo ""

            # Reset the username
            $userName = $null
        }
    }

    # Variable to store user info + fill it
    $userData = [String]::Format("User:;{0}`r`nDisplay Name:;{1}`r`nE-mail:;{2}`r`nSharePoint ID:;{3}`r`nSite Admin:;{4}`r`n`r`nGroups:", $getUserInfo.UserLogin, $getUserInfo.Name, $getUserInfo.Email, $getUserInfo.ID, $getUserInfo.IsSiteAdmin)
    echo ($userData.replace(";","`t"))

    # Check if the data need to be written to CVS
    if($doExport)
    {
        writeToCSV -textToWrite $userData -filePath $exportPath
    }

    # Loop through the groups
    foreach($group in $getUserGroups)
    {
        # Variable to store the data
        $groupInfo = [String]::Format(";{0}", $group.Name)
        echo $groupInfo.replace(";","`t")

        # Check if the data need to be written to CVS
        if($doExport)
        {
            writeToCSV -textToWrite $groupInfo -filePath $exportPath
        }
    }

    # Check if the data need to be written to CVS
    echo ""
    if($doExport)
    {
        Write-Warning ("The file has been stored at: " + $exportPath)
    }
    echo ""
}

# Appends the text to the file in ASCII
function writeToCSV($textToWrite, $filePath)
{
    # Write as ASCII
    ($textToWrite) | Out-File $filePath -Append -Encoding ASCII
}

# Checks if the path exists, if it does, the file gets deleted
function deleteExisting($filePathToCheck)
{
    # Check if the path exists
    if(Test-Path -LiteralPath $filePathToCheck)
    {
        # The file exists, so delete it
        Remove-Item -LiteralPath $filePathToCheck
    }
}

# Opens a folder browser dialog
function Select-Folder($title='Select a folder', $path = 0) 
{  
    #   Create a new shell object
    $object = New-Object -comObject Shell.Application   

    #   Open the browser dialog
    $folder = $object.BrowseForFolder(0, $title, 0, $path)  

    #   Return the selected path
    return $folder.self.Path
}

############################
############################

# Ask the user what web to connect to
$webUrl = (Read-Host -Prompt "URL of the web to connect to").trim()

# Try to connect to the web
$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl

# Ask the user which action to perform
CLS
$selectedVal = -1
while($selectedVal -eq -1)
{
    echo ""
    echo "Actions:"
    echo ""

    echo "1 . Export permission groups on this web to CSV"
    echo "2.  Export users that have permissions on this web to CSV"
    echo "3.  Export permission groups including users on this web CSV"
    echo "4.  Export permissions a single user on this web to CSV"
    echo ""
    echo "-1. Display permission groups on this web"
    echo "-2. Display users that have permissions on this web"
    echo "-3. Display permission groups including users"
    echo "-4. Display permissions of a single user on this web"

    echo ""
    $selectedVal = Read-Host -Prompt "Which action would you like to perform?"

    switch($selectedVal)
    {
        ####
        # EXPORT
        ####

        # 1 was selected
        1 { 
            exportPermissionGroup -fileNameToUse ($web.Title + "_Group_Export") -doExport $true
        }

        # 2 was selected
        2 {
            exportWebUsers -fileNameToUse ($web.Title + "_User_Export") -doExport $true
        }

        # 3 was selected
        3 {
            exportGroupAndUsers -fileNameToUse ($web.Title + "_Group_And_User_Export") -doExport $true
        }

        # 4 was selected
        4 {
            exportSingleUser -fileNameToUse ($web.Title + "_Single_User_Export") -doExport $true
        }

        ####
        # NO EXPORT
        ####

        # -1 was selected
        -1 { 
            exportPermissionGroup -fileNameToUse $null -doExport $false
        }

        # -2 was selected
        -2 {
            exportWebUsers -fileNameToUse $null -doExport $false
        }

        # -3 was selected
        -3 {
            exportGroupAndUsers -fileNameToUse $null -doExport $false
        }

        # -4 was selected
        -4 {
            exportSingleUser  -fileNameToUse $null -doExport $false
        }

        default {
            # Invalid selection
            CLS
            echo ("")
            Write-Warning "The selection you made is invalid, please try again..."
            echo ("")

            # Reset the selected value
            $selectedVal = -1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not very readable when opened in excel but works.

Answer (score 0):

try below code( [complete details](http://johanmeyer.ukuvuma.co.za/2013/02/22/export-all-user-permissions-from-a-sharepoint-2010-site-to-csv/))

```
function Get-SPUserEffectivePermissions(
    [object[]]$users, 
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObject]$InputObject) {

    begin { }
    process {
        $so = $InputObject
        if ($so -eq $null) { $so = $_ }

        if ($so -isnot [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObject]) {
            throw "A valid SPWeb, SPList, or SPListItem must be provided."
        }

        foreach ($user in $users) {
            # Set the users login name
            $loginName = $user
            if ($user -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser] -or $user -is [PSCustomObject]) {
                $loginName = $user.LoginName
            }
            if ($loginName -eq $null) {
                throw "The provided user is null or empty. Specify a valid SPUser object or login name."
            }

            # Get the users permission details.
            $permInfo = $so.GetUserEffectivePermissionInfo($loginName)

            # Determine the URL to the securable object being evaluated
            $resource = $null
            if ($so -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb]) {
                $resource = $so.Url
            } elseif ($so -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList]) {
                $resource = $so.ParentWeb.Site.MakeFullUrl($so.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl)
            } elseif ($so -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem]) {
                $resource = $so.ParentList.ParentWeb.Site.MakeFullUrl($so.Url)
            }

            # Get the role assignments and iterate through them
            $roleAssignments = $permInfo.RoleAssignments
            if ($roleAssignments.Count -gt 0) {
                foreach ($roleAssignment in $roleAssignments) {
                    $member = $roleAssignment.Member

                    # Build a string array of all the permission level names
                    $permName = @()
                    foreach ($definition in $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings) {
                        $permName += $definition.Name
                    }

                    # Determine how the users permissions were assigned
                    $assignment = "Direct Assignment"
                    if ($member -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroup]) {
                        $assignment = $member.Name
                    } else {
                        if ($member.IsDomainGroup -and ($member.LoginName -ne $loginName)) {
                            $assignment = $member.LoginName
                        }
                    }

                    # Create a hash table with all the data
                    $hash = @{
                        Resource = $resource
                        "Resource Type" = $so.GetType().Name
                        User = $loginName
                        Permission = $permName -join ", "
                        "Granted By" = $assignment
                    }

                    # Convert the hash to an object and output to the pipeline
                    New-Object PSObject -Property $hash
                }
            }
        }
    }
    end {}
}


$site = $gc | Get-SPSite  http://localhost:2015
$groups = $site.RootWeb.sitegroups

 foreach ($grp in $groups) {
    foreach ($user in $grp.users) 
        {
            $user = $user.LoginName
            $webPermissions = $site | Get-SPWeb –Limit All | Get-SPUserEffectivePermissions $user
            $listPermissions = $site | Get-SPWeb –Limit All | %{$_.Lists | Get-SPUserEffectivePermissions $user}
            ($webPermissions + $listPermissions) | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Add-Content -Path c:\perms.csv 
        } 
        Add-Content -Path c:\perms.csv -Value $justData -Encoding UTF8
}
$site.Dispose()






$gc | Stop-SPAssignment
```

Comment: Get an error:
 Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] doesn'
t contain a method named 'op_Addition'.

Comment: did you try to donwload the script from the blog directly?